# SQL Server : get records where dates are in specific time fram

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

Let's say I have the folling table

```
EventName    |   eventStartDate  |   eventEndDate
--------------------------------------------------
Event 1      |  11/11/2015       |   01/31/2016
Event 2      |  01/24/2016       |   01/26/2016
Event 3      |  02/23/2015       |   03/20/2016
Event 4      |  02/20/2016       |   02/26/2016
```

I'd like to write query that gets all the events where the event takes place within a calendar month. So for example I want to get all events that are active in January. This would leave me with Event 1, Event 2 and Event 3

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Your definition  "active in January" is too vague, you should define it more precisely. Is it particular January of, say 2016 year or January of any year? And what about activity - should event be selected if it started in Jan but ended in another later month? Or started in December and ended in January? Is it just "at least one day from period should be in January of any year"?

Comment: OK, so i'm looking for a query that will return all events where the date between the eventStartDate  and eventEndDate would be within January 2016. So the query should return Events 1, 2 and 3. All of these events will be taking place at some point between Jan 01 2016 and Jan 31 2016

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a bunch of conditions like:

```
select * 
from your_table
where
     (eventStartDate >= '20160101' and eventStartDate <= '20160131')
     or
     (eventEndDate >= '20160101' and eventEndDate <= '20160131')
     or
     (eventStartDate <= '20160101' and eventEndDate >= '20160131')
```

First one defines period that starts in Jan.

Second one defines perion that ends in Jan.

Third one defines period that starts before and ends after Jan (inclusively).

Obviously - there are no other periods intersecting this particular January possible.

**Update:**

All these conditions could be simplified to:

```
select * 
from your_table
where eventStartDate <= '20160131' and eventEndDate >= '20160101'
```

This condition still defines all three periods mentioned above, but significantly shorter.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be to compute a six-digit number for each month and then use the `BETWEEN`operator:

```
SELECT
     [EventName]
     , [eventStartDate]
     , [eventEndDate]
FROM [tblEvents]
WHERE 201601 BETWEEN YEAR([eventStartDate]) * 100 + MONTH([eventStartDate]) AND YEAR([eventEndDate]) * 100 + MONTH([eventEndDate])
```

**Update:** With huge data sets, however, there will be a lot of computing going on, so performance has to be kept in mind.

Comment: While it will work good at small amount of data - it will be pretty slow at very large amounts of data. The reason is any computations made on columns in `where` condition (like `YEAR([eventStartDate])` in your sample) will prevent usage of indexes built on this column, so SQL server will have to scan all the table and compute conditions for every row.

Comment: I was just adding this :) Though not as elaborate as you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE 
@CurrentMonth int =1 -- MONTH IN NUMBERS

Please this 

SELECT *
    EventName    
    ,eventStartDate  
    ,eventEndDate
FROM EVENTs
WHERE
YEAR(eventStartDate) =YEAR(GETUTCDATE())
AND (MONTH(eventStartDate)>= @CurrentMonth AND MONTH(eventStartDate)<(@CurrentMonth+1))
```